# Find if pod is being terminated due to statefulset deletion

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I need to perform some operations on a different server statefulset when pods inside a client statefulset comes down only because of a statefulset deletion. I can trap the sigterm signal which is sent during pod termination from inside the pod, but how do i figure out whether the termination is during a statefulset deletion because pods can come down/terminate for various other reasons. Does statefulset have its own status? because i see that statefulset status only shows the status of the pods when i do a describe. I use client-go.

Kubectl describe statefulset doesnt have a status of its own but only of the pods associated.

Comment: You could watch the other StatefulSet and take action when it's deleted, rather than trying to infer the reason a Pod is being deleted.  You also might tie this activity to some other custom resource where you more directly control and monitor its life cycle.

Comment: In our arch, the server cannot decide this, it has to be client(pod) initiated. How would the custom resouce know if the statefulset was deleted except for polling once in a while ? The deletion is not under my(software) control. Consumer would delete it.

Comment: ...so the software running in the pod takes different action if its pod is being deleted specifically because the StatefulSet is being deleted, as distinct from updating the StatefulSet, getting evicted from its node, or something else?  What should happen if the StatefulSet is recreated with the same underlying PersistentVolumeClaims?  Can you make a request to the pod to initiate an orderly shutdown, instead of trying to infer it from the Kubernetes layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the statefulset object is deleted first and then pods are deleted in a cascading fashion. so when i trap SIGTERM, and try to query the statefulset in my code, i already receive statefulset "abc" not found. So i will use this to know that the statefulset is deleted.

By default, Kubernetes uses background cascading deletion to delete dependents of an object
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#background-deletion

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the Kubernetes event indicating that a stateful set has been deleted, similar to the way [this kube events exporter](https://github.com/kubesphere/kube-events) works.

That way, whenever the code detects an event indicating that a statefulset has been deleted, you can act accordingly.